# CustomAuthenticationProvider is not being called when using http.authorizeHttpRequests()

Tags: spring-security

I am studying Spring,

I have a simple Spring Boot project (version 2.7.9) which enables JWT login functionality. I have faced a problem when I configure security java configuration. I have a Custom Authentication Provider bean, and it only works when I use `http.authorizeRequests()` method which is deprecated in a newer version, otherwise, when I use `http.authorizeHttpRequests()`, the provider not being called.

Here is my security java config code:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig {
    
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests( 
                    // when I use authorizeHttpRequests(), my custom authentication provider does not be called..
                    authorize -> authorize
                                    .antMatchers("/user/signup", "/user/login").permitAll()
                                    .anyRequest().authenticated())
            .authenticationProvider(jwtAuthenticationProvider())
            
            .csrf()
                .disable()
                
            .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
                
            .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
            
            ;
            
        
        return http.build();
    }

    
    @Bean
    public OncePerRequestFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter() {
        return new JwtAuthenticationFilter();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider jwtAuthenticationProvider() {
        return new JwtAuthenticationProvider();
    }
```

To enable JWT login, I have a custom OncePerRequestFilter which receives jwt header, extracts claims and make a UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken, and set it by `SecurityContextHolder.getContext.setAuthentication(authentication)`.
And my provider gets the authentication object, casting to UsernamePasswordAuthentication token, check user credentials, if validates successful, then return the token in `@Override AuthenticationProvider.authenticate()` method.

Here is my filter code:

```
public class JwtAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JwtAuthenticationFilter.class);
    
    @Autowired
    private JwtProcessor jwtProcessor;
    
    
    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        logger.info("filter is working on..");
        String authHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        
        if(authHeader != null) {
            logger.info("found an authorization header in my filter..");    
            String jwt = authHeader.substring("bearer: ".length());
            Map<String, Object> claims = jwtProcessor.validateJwt(jwt);
            
            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken token = createToken(jwt, claims);
            
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(token);
        }
        
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }


    private UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken createToken(String jwt, Map<String, Object> claims) {
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken token = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(jwt, claims);
        token.setAuthenticated(false);
        return token;
    }

}
```

My filter extends `OncePerRequestFilter`, not the one `AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter`.
Because I do not know how it works - the abstract thing filter uses an entry point, and many people use the  enrty point on '/login', and I think given the entry point, this filter intercepts the request, and make login logic, but I have a '/login' entry in my controller which returns JWT code, so I could not use `AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter`.

and here is my provider code:

```
public class JwtAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider{

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JwtAuthenticationProvider.class);
    
    @Autowired
    private UserAuthenticationService userAuthenticationService;
    
    
    @Override
    public Authentication    authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        
        logger.info("provider is working on..");
        
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken token = (UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken) authentication;
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        Map<String,Object> claims = (Map<String, Object>)token.getCredentials();
        
        String email = claims.get("email").toString();
        String password = claims.get("password").toString();
        
        userAuthenticationService.loadUser(email, password);// throw badcredentialexception when no match found
        
        return token;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
        return UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class.isAssignableFrom(authentication);
    }

}
```

Since `HttpSecurity.authorizeRequests()` is deprecated in a newer version, I have to use `HttpSecurity.authorizeHttpRequests()` which does not use my CustomAuthenticationProvider.

So my question is, why does not my provider be called when using `HttpSecurity.authorizeHttpRequests()` ?

sorry for my bad english skill..

**EDIT**
I have read a part of Spring Security doc,
and there is a jwt-functionality example code.

[official example code link here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-samples/tree/main/servlet/spring-boot/java/jwt/login)

Using the sample code, I can barely customize it.
To more specifically say, I can customize only UserDetailsService....
Though I want to handle extracting `scope variable` in the jwt token to do more additional job while authentication, I've could not do that...

Here is my updated version of my security config code.
In SecurityFilterChain bean, I used oauth2resourceServer method - I just copied the sample code.

```
package com.aibiigae1221.cookcook;
import java.security.interfaces.RSAPrivateKey;
import java.security.interfaces.RSAPublicKey;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.Customizer;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.oauth2.server.resource.OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.factory.PasswordEncoderFactories;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtDecoder;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.NimbusJwtDecoder;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.NimbusJwtEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.web.BearerTokenAuthenticationEntryPoint;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.web.access.BearerTokenAccessDeniedHandler;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.HttpStatusReturningLogoutSuccessHandler;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfigurationSource;
import org.springframework.web.cors.UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource;

import com.aibiigae1221.cookcook.security.CustomUserDetailsService;
import com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.JWK;
import com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.JWKSet;
import com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.RSAKey;
import com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.source.ImmutableJWKSet;
import com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.source.JWKSource;
import com.nimbusds.jose.proc.SecurityContext;

@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig {
    @Value("${jwt.public.key}")
    RSAPublicKey pubKey;

    @Value("${jwt.private.key}")
    RSAPrivateKey privKey;
    

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> 
                        authorize
                            .requestMatchers("/sign-up", "/login").permitAll()
                            .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .cors()
                    .configurationSource(corsConfiguration()).and()
                .csrf().disable()
                .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .oauth2ResourceServer(OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer::jwt)
                .sessionManagement((session) -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .exceptionHandling((exceptions) -> exceptions
                        .authenticationEntryPoint(new BearerTokenAuthenticationEntryPoint())
                        .accessDeniedHandler(new BearerTokenAccessDeniedHandler())
                )
                .logout()
                    .logoutUrl("/logout")
                    .clearAuthentication(true)
                    .logoutSuccessHandler(new HttpStatusReturningLogoutSuccessHandler());

        return http.build();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfiguration() {
        CorsConfiguration cors = new CorsConfiguration();
        cors.setAllowedOrigins(List.of("http://localhost:3000", "http://127.0.0.1:3000"));
        cors.addAllowedMethod("*");     
        cors.addAllowedHeader("*");
        
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", cors);
        return source;
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return new CustomUserDetailsService();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    JwtDecoder jwtDecoder() {
        return NimbusJwtDecoder.withPublicKey(this.pubKey).build();
    }

    @Bean
    JwtEncoder jwtEncoder() {
        JWK jwk = new RSAKey.Builder(this.pubKey).privateKey(this.privKey).build();
        JWKSource<SecurityContext> jwks = new ImmutableJWKSet<>(new JWKSet(jwk));
        return new NimbusJwtEncoder(jwks);
    }
    
    
}
```

Comment: you are aware that the handling of JWTs is already implemented in spring security?

Comment: I haven't know that. thanks for informing me, I will check out.

Comment: @Toerktumlare It looks like Spring has implemented JWT with OAuth 2.0. I think I have to know about OAuth 2.0 first. This question has to be closed..

Comment: Spring implements the "resource server" section of the oauth 2.0 specification which is exactly what you are trying to implement by yourself. Thats when passing a JWT to the server, it needs to be verified and then a principal needs to built from it. If you want to learn spring seccurity, i recommend you go through the documentation from the start and then try building all the authentication mechanisms one by one.

Comment: @Toerktumlare Thanks you, that helps me. I will read it soon